# Is there any specified url format on Huawei AppGallery so I can reach & distribute the link on different platforms

Tags: android, huawei-mobile-services, huawei-developers

Is there a specific URL format for a link to AppGallery listing for my application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Long link
   A long link is a link of App Linking in its entirety, and generally follows this format:

**URL prefix + Deep link + Android app parameters + Social sharing identifier parameters + Site ID**

·        The URL prefix is the URL contained in a link, which is in https://Domain name format. You can use the domain name provided by AppGallery Connect for free.

·        The deep link is the URL of your app content. This is where a user will be directed when they tap the link. So if you want the user to see a specific page when they tap a link, you can set the URL of that page as the deep link.

·        Android app parameters include the APK name, the link that will be opened if your app is not installed, and the earliest version of your app where the link can be opened.

·        Social sharing identifier parameters define what information will appear when the link is shared on social platforms. Links can currently be shared on Facebook, Messenger, Twitter, and WhatsApp.

·        The site ID is determined based on the data storage location of your app. It is used to identify the site that provides the App Linking service for your app.

For more information about long links, please refer to : https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/AppGallery-connect-Guides/agc-applinking-createlinks-defined

2. Short link
   If a long link is too long, it can be converted to a short link. A short link follows this format:

**URL prefix + Random suffix of the string type**

The suffix of a short link can be long or short. A long suffix contains 17 characters. A short suffix contains at least four random characters.

For details, see : https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/AppGallery-connect-Guides/agc-applinking-introduction

Answer (score 4):

The URL you're looking for looks like this:

`https://appgallery.cloud.huawei.com/ag/n/app/C<appID>` ([real example](https://appgallery.cloud.huawei.com/ag/n/app/C100236459))

The best way to distribute the link would be to create a badge via App Gallery Connect as instructed [here](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/AppGallery-connect-Guides/appgallery-agd-create-stamped).